# how to auto-increment column value starting from value other than one in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, default, auto-increment

i have an existing mysql table with the id column defined as primary, and auto-increment set as true. now, i would like to know if i can set the auto-increment to start from a predefined value, say 5678, instead of starting off from 1.

I would also like to know if i can set the steps for auto-incrementing, say increase by 15 each for each new record insertion (instead of the default increment value of 1).

Note- i am using phpmyadmin to play with the db, and i have many tables but only one db.

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this is the correct way to do it but I would do this in php outside of the database. Mind if I ask why you would want this?

Comment: I have been trying to find a reason why would you need this but I could think of none! Help a troubling soul with revealing the reason for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [server-system-variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html):

[auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)

and

[auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset)

This will allow you to increase the offset by other values than 1 (e.g. 15) each time.
If you start from a different value using the same offset on a different server. This will allow you to keep tables on different servers that can be merged without keys overlapping.

e.g.

```
(inc = 15 offset = 1)          (inc=15 offset = 2)
table1 on server A             table1 on server B
-----------------------------------------------------
id     name                    id    name
1      bill                    2     john
16     monica                  17    claire 
....
```

This can be very useful.

Because the main usage is to have the **same table** on **different servers** behave in a different way, it is a server setting and not a table setting.

Answer (score 5):

`ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 5678` will set the auto increment to 5678 for that table. Have a look at the detailed information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the auto increment value using below command

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 5678;
```

And can update the auto_increment counter variable using below command

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=15;
```

Loo at [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) for more info

```
mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment=15;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc1 VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT col FROM autoinc1;
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
|   1 |
|  16 |
|  31 |
|  46 |
```

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE whatever AUTO_INCREMENT=5678` - alternatively in phpMyAdmin, go to the "Operations" tab of the table view and set it there. For the increment step, use the setting  [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example here..
http://pranaydac08.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-set-auto-increment-value-start-from.html